# How to restore window decorations for maximized windows in unity?

Tags: unity

For no obvious reason I lost the decorations for maximized windows (close, minimize, resize buttons) and the possibility to change windows when clicking on the application symol in the starter (a new instance is started all the time).

In the `compizconfig-settings-manager` (`ccsm`) I can reactivate the decorations, but the window decorations plugin in incompatible with the unity plugin and with it using `unity` doesn't make too much sense. There's no other setting which jumped into my eye in both plugins which could get the decorations back. I can't simply try them because I already experienced default settings in `ccsm` to be incompatible with each other so that changes consequently require resetting `unity`.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `unity --reset` fixes this issue.